# Windows Embedded Compact 7: Developing?? Visual Studio 2010?? Templates?

Tags: c#, windows-embedded

I would like to develop for Windows Embedded, but can't find any easy tutorials.

I have looked [here](http://www.microsoft.com/showcase/en/us/channels/windowsembedded/search?phrase=compact%207) and [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/develop/windows-embedded-compact-7-for-developers.aspx)

Does it just work on Silverlight, or something special?

There doesn't seem to be any templates for VS 201

Comment: I can't find any evidence of WEC7 being supported on VS 2010. Odd. (I'm using ultimate version)

Comment: From: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/icumove/archive/2011/03/02/windows-embedded-compact-7-evaluation-download.aspx
Brian Rogers Microsoft
14 Jul 2011 7:01 PM
NJK Thanks for your comment. Our team is investigating what it will take to add Visual Studio 2010 support, as well as several other interesting new feature requests. We're at a very early stage and don't have anything more to announce at this time. Our team is working on an updated Compact roadmap and expect to release it **at the end of the year.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

start here

http://www.microsoft.com/windowsembedded/en-us/develop/windows-embedded-products-for-developers.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/usisvde/archive/2009/08/11/windows-embedded-development-center-updated-on-msdn.aspx

search MSDN, you will find what you are looking for

Comment: everything points to installing VS 2008. Is that where we start development? I'm already using VS 2010 ultimate.

Comment: EDIT [post 5 minutes] found answer on MS blog.

Comment: @Jeremy, could you write the answer here? I can't find it in my 10 minutes of searching because some of the links are stale.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a step by step tutorial by Samuel Phung:

> The Windows Embedded Compact 7 (Compact 7) getting started series is
>   created to provide simple and easy to follow information to help
>   academic, hobbyist and commercial developers to learn and engage in
>   Compact 7 development.

http://www.embedded101.com/Compact7

Also his book:
[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Windows-Embedded-Compact-7/dp/1118050460](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1118050460)